# my npm start not work when i start first time its working but i check this after some time its not working now

Tags: reactjs

> starchat@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-core/lib/ReplaceSource'
Require stack:

- D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlockVariable.js
- D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlock.js
- D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Module.js
- D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js
- D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlockVariable.js:5:21)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlockVariable.js',
  'D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\DependenciesBlock.js',
  'D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Module.js',
  'D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js',
  'D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js',
  'D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js',
  'D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js'
  ]
  }

Comment: make sure you are inside `D:\programming language\whatapp clone\starchat` folder. Or if it also not solve then try `npm install` command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.